# Is mounting C drive owned by the default user and not root is possible under WSL without updating to windows insider?

Tags: windows-10, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-insider

I know it is possible to config the mounting points and options on `/etc/wsl.conf` and `/etc/fstab` after [windows insider build 17093](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/). However, I am using the university machine and it is advised to not use nor windows insider updates neither windows updates and I prefer to obey this policy as I much as I can. They said so as they had this problem few months ago that students lost their data after an update. Now they control the updates.

What I would like is to change the mounting configurations so that `c` gets mounted with `umask=22` and under a user different than `root`.

I am asking if at all there is any such configuration before windows insider version so that I won't waste my time anymore.

Comment: How about installing latest Windows stable build?

Comment: Which version? Does that include insider build 17093 features? My current build is 16299.15 and the version is 1709. It is a Windows 10 Education edition.

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect the situation that even it is advised to not use windows updates. Instead we should use some of those they give us through some software center application.

Comment: I mean the latest 1809 version aka. October update 2018.

Comment: Although it was against the recommended policies, it did work. Yet still the answer to my question is NO I suppose. I just want someone who is 100% sure to answer it as no.